# Not able to filter Checkbox value using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, filter

I have almost 10 checkbox with values.

I want to filter the checkbox based on their value, but currently I am not able to

I cannot can change the HTML code, but I don't know why it is not filtering the checkbox

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Options search field
    $('#options').before(
      '<input id="search" style="display: inline; width:180px;" type="text" />' +
      '<span><a href="" onclick="return false;" id="search-clear">X</a></span>'
    );
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
      var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        //use checkbox val
        var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        //closest to hide lis
        (text.indexOf(valThis) > -1 ) ? $(this).closest('li').show(): $(this).closest('li').hide();
      });
    });
    // Search clear button
    $("#search-clear").click(function() {
      $("#search").val("");
      $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        $(this).closest('li').show();
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="options">
      <div class="col s12  ">

        <label>Server</label>

        <div id="id_form-0-server">
          <ul>
            <li class="">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="ABC" id="id_form-0-server_0"> 
                <span>ABC-1-2</span>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="EFD" id="id_form-0-server_1">
                <span>EFD-1-3</span>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="KIS" id="id_form-0-server_2">
                <span>KIS-1-46</span>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="PNJS" id="id_form-0-server_3">
                <span>PNJS-1</span>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="PJSGRA" id="id_form-0-server_4">
                <span>PJSGRA-1-10</span>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="KLSCV" id="id_form-0-server_5">
                <span>KLSCV-1</span>
              </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**

- EDIT :

**

Edited the code as per Swati's instruction , but getting another issue , what if i have to filter table using span value rather than checkbox attribute value is that possible . like i want the filter to perform based on the value shown in UI rather that the checkbox attribute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a filter

```js
$(function() {
  const $lis = $("#id_form-0-server li");
  const showAll = () => $lis.show();

  // Options search field
  $('#options').before(
    '<input id="search" style="display: inline; width:180px;" type="text" autocomplete="off" />' +
    ' <span><a href="#" id="search-clear">X</a></span>'
  );

  $('#search').on("input", function() {
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (valThis.trim() === "") {
      showAll()
      return
    }
    showAll();
    $lis.filter(function() {
      return !$(this).find('span').text().toLowerCase().includes(valThis)
    }).hide();
  });
  // Search clear button
  $("#search-clear").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#search").val("");
    showAll()
  })
});
```

```css
a { text-decoration:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="options">
  <div class="col s12  ">

    <label>Server</label>

    <div id="id_form-0-server">
      <ul>
        <li class="">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="ABC" id="id_form-0-server_0"> 
            <span>ABC</span>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="EFD" id="id_form-0-server_1">
            <span>EFD</span>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="KIS" id="id_form-0-server_2">
            <span>KIS</span>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="PNJS" id="id_form-0-server_3">
            <span>PNJS</span>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="PJSGRA" id="id_form-0-server_4">
            <span>PJSGRA</span>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="KLSCV" id="id_form-0-server_5">
            <span>KLSCV</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: but this will not work if i give different values for the Span and Input . Actually i want to perform filtering based on Span value

Comment: No problem, I changed the code to use the span instead

Comment: I also removed the inline click on the clear and added a preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

Your checkbox already have `value ="youareseacrhing"` you can use that to make your search work.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Options search field
    $('#options').before(
      '<input id="search" style="display: inline; width:180px;" type="text" />' +
      '<span><a href="" onclick="return false;" id="search-clear">X</a></span>'
    );
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
      var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $('li span').each(function() {
        //use checkbox val
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        //closest to hide lis
        (text.indexOf(valThis) > -1) ? $(this).closest('li').show(): $(this).closest('li').hide();
      });
    });
    // Search clear button
    $("#search-clear").click(function() {
      $("#search").val("");
      $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        $(this).closest('li').show();
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="options">
  <div class="col s12  ">

    <label>Server</label>

    <div id="id_form-0-server">
      <ul>
        <li class="">
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="ABC" id="id_form-0-server_0"> 
                <span>ABC-1-2</span>
              </label>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="EFD" id="id_form-0-server_1">
                <span>EFD-1-3</span>
              </label>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="KIS" id="id_form-0-server_2">
                <span>KIS-1-46</span>
              </label>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="PNJS" id="id_form-0-server_3">
                <span>PNJS-1</span>
              </label>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="PJSGRA" id="id_form-0-server_4">
                <span>PJSGRA-1-10</span>
              </label>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-server" value="KLSCV" id="id_form-0-server_5">
                <span>KLSCV-1</span>
              </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

.

Comment: this is working if i enter everything in same order like ABC  , but if i search just BY , then it is showing me empty results . but i want the filter to work even if i enter BY

Comment: Code smell to have a ternary use a sideeffect.

Comment: So what if my checkbox value and the attribute value is diff @Swati , i will update my code , can you kindly check

Answer (score -1):

Probably because when you get the text of the corresponding label you're also getting a load of whitespace, and not trimming it off.

Anyway, the chekboxes' `value` attribute seems to correspond to the label text, so why not use that for comparison instead?

Change

```
var text = $("label[for='"+$(this).attr('id')+"']").text().toLowerCase();
(text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).parent().show() : $(this).parent().hide();
```

to

```
$(this).parent()[this.value.indexOf(valThis) === 0 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
```

Comment: Really? I tried it with your HTML and it works perfectly.